# What comic book are Young Sheldon and Paige talking about in the carbon dating museum?

Tags: story-identification, comics, the-big-bang-theory

Paige asks Sheldon if humans will become extinct like dinosaurs and Sheldon replies,

> Yes, but not before some of us merge with computers and become immortal cyborgs.

Sheldon then says he got the idea from a comic book. Anyone know which comic book that is?

Comment: Many many of them

Comment: @Valorum Any examples?

Comment: See https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BrainUploading under comic books.